# Teradata - OLAP Functions - filter rows

Tags: teradata

I'm wondering if I can use an OLAP Function to filter irrelevant rows like this:

If I have one matching value (the fourth fields)  all the rows with the same key ( the first 3 fields) must not be displayed

In this example, the matching value would be 'C':

```
       Entities     product     ID     Solde
        997          0050          123     D
        997          0050          123     D
        997          0050          123     C
        899          0124          125     D
        899          0124          125     D
```

So here My key is composed by entities/product/ID, regarding the value of "Solde" I need to display or not.

Here the the undesired value is Solde = C.

In this example only the last row should be diplayed, because the key 899/0124/125 has only rows with solde = 'D'

The key 997/0050/123 has one row with solde = 'C' so I don't want to display it

Thanks in advance for your helping

Christophe

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to filter out records for distinct `Entities, product, id` where the `Solde` has a duplicate... only keeping records that have a distinct `Solde` for the `Entities, product, id` combination?

Comment: No, I want to display only the row with solde = D only. If for 1 row I have solde = C I don't want to display it. In this example no row should be displayed because the third row has solde = C

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer**

The more traditional way to solve this is to first select the Entities/Product/ID records that you DON'T want.

```
 SELECT Entities, Product, ID FROM table WHERE Solde<>'D';
```

Use that result in a subquery in your WHERE clause to exclude those:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Entities, Product, ID, Solde
FROM table
WHERE (Entities, Product, ID) NOT IN ( SELECT Entities, Product, ID FROM table WHERE Solde<>'D');
```

Alternatively using a HAVING clause and aggregating

```
SELECT Entities, Product, ID
FROM table
COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN Solde = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: You may get different/better performance with a correlated subquery `from table t1 where NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from table t2 where t2.Entities = t1.Entities and t2.Product = t1.Product and t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.solde <> 'D' )`. Depending (as usual) on data size and distribution. `NOT EXISTS` uses a shortcut if the first occurence is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for answer as the below:

SELECT Solde
FROM yourtable
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Entities, Product, ID, Solde) = 1;